# Why can't security administrator see resources in a subscription?

Tags: security, rbac, azure-rbac, cloud-security, azure-defender

I have **Security administrator** role on a subscription. Now, what I want to see is the resources available in the subscription to know the attack surface, but when I go to the resources tab, I see nothing Or if I check the VMs tab I cannot see any VM (even though they're available). Similarly, on the defender plans page, it shows all the resources as 0 whereas that's not the case.

[image: Defender Plans Page]

Why being a security admin I cant see this data? Doesn't it come under my scope? If not, then what additional role I need to see this data. Obviously, I can't ask for Contributor consider the least privilege principle

I tried accessing resource details but couldn't. I was expecting to have access to this data as a security admin.

Comment: Try adding reader role and you will be able to access resources

Comment: @Rukmini isn't security admin role superior to reader and covers all the permissions that a reader holds?

Comment: Security admin can read security information and reports, and manage configuration in Microsoft Entra ID and Office 365 but not view Azure resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: Security Administrator role will be able to read security information and reports and manage configuration in Microsoft Entra ID and Office 365 but not to view Azure resources. Check this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/permissions-reference#all-roles).

- The Security Administrator role does not provide access to view all resources in the subscription.

Hence assign **Reader role** to the user at subscription scope or resource group scope based on your requirement:

[image]

***Now I am able to view the resources:***

[image]

*If you want to manage resources, then you have to assign contributor/owner role to the user.*

**Reference:**

[Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#all)